# Identifying 5 unknown substances

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, identification

I need help identifying the following 5 substances; G, Y, T, L and J

> G is a white solid which is insoluble in water. Consider the following reactions carried out on solid G.
>
> **Step 1:**
> Excess dilute nitric acid is added to a small amount of G in a test-tube. A colourless and odourless gas Y is given off and it is noticed that Y extinguishes a lighted splint.
> The solution remaining in the test tube is divided into two different test tubes, sample A and sample B.
> **Step 2:**
> A few drops of potassium iodide solution are added to a sample A and a bright yellow precipitate L is observed.
> **Step 3:**
> Sodium hydroxide solution is added drop wise to sample B. A dense white precipitate, T, is immediately observed. Precipitate T dissolves when excess sodium hydroxide solution is added to it.
> **Step 4:**
> When some G is heated in a hard glass tube, gas Y which is colourless and odourless is given off. The solid J remaining in the hard glass tube changes colour on cooling from red-brown to yellow.

These are my solutions:

- G = $\ce{PbCO3}$ because
- Y = $\ce{CO2}$ - colourless and odourless gas
- L = $\ce{PbI2}$
- T = $\ce{Pb(OH)2}$
- J = $\ce{PbO2}$

Are they correct or not?

Comment: Your solutions sound good so far. But why do you think product I is $\ce{PbO2}$ and not, for example, $\ce{PbO}$? How would you explain the color change during cooling of I?

Answer (score 11):

If you don't have any idea:

- Start with the hypothesis that your starting material is the salt of some metal.
- Some of the test are apparently useful to identify the cation, others tackle the anion.
- Is it likely that the flame-extinguishing gas comes from the cation?
- If it is not the cation, it must be the anion from which the gas is formed.
- Think in the main property of **diluted** nitric **acid**. Is it an oxidant in diluted form, or just something else?

I almost completely agree with the solution given in the question, except for the last step.

The three known lead oxides are

1. $\ce{PbO2}$: dark brown to black, strong oxidant
2. $\ce{Pb3O4}$: red-orange, used as a rust-proof primer (in German: *Bleimenninge*)
3. $\ce{PbO}$: (normally) yellow

When dark $\ce{PbO2}$ is heated, it splits off oxygen to form red $\ce{Pb3O4}$, when it's heated up more, more oxygen is released and yellow $\ce{PbO}$ is formed. Properly done in a quartz tube the colours of the German flag can be produced this way.

In the puzzle, we are not starting with $\ce{PbO2}$ but with $\ce{PbCO3}$.

When $\ce{PbCO3}$(= **G**) is heated, $\ce{CO2}$ (= **Y**) is released. The questions mentions a *hard glass tube*, which suggests that the tube has to withstand high temperatures.

Let's assume that the reaction simply is $\ce{PbCO3 ->[\Delta] PbO + CO2 ^}$

A possible explanation for the colour change would be that at high temperatures, red $\ce{\alpha-PbO}$ is initially formed, which converts to yellow $\ce{\beta-PbO}$ upon cooling.